# UIButton as UINavigationbar button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I have a Tab bar application. and in one of the tab bars I have a navigation contorller.
Im trying to set a UIButton with an image as the right button the navigation bar.

```
    UIButton *refreshButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [refreshButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [refreshButton addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshSection) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:refreshButton];
    //[rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh_icon.png"]]; << DOESN'T WORK EITHER  
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
    [refreshButton release];
    [rightButton release];
```

but the image doesn't show up. I get an invisible button.

**EDIT:**
I want the button style to be plain or background to be transparent, so that only the image shows. Hence I am using a UIbutton instead of using a UIBarButton directly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't have to create a `UIButton` and use it as custom view in the `UIBarButtonItem`. You can create a `UIBarButtonItem` directly with an image:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:myImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(refreshSection)];  
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;    
[button release];
```

--

**Updated, according to comments**

Use a `UIImageView` as custom view in the `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageView];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
[imageView release];
[rightButton release];
```

--

**Updated**

Tried the last approach and while this does visually look like you want it to, I can't seem to get it to handle taps. Although the target and action has been set.

--

**Final update**

I've gotten your initial code in the question up & running. The reason the image is not showing, is because you haven't set the frame of the button. Once you set the frame, the image is shown in the navigation bar.

Here's my snippet I used & tested:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paw.png"];
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height);

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

[rightButton release];
[myButton release];
```

Note: I have set the `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` property of the `UIButton` to visually hightlight the button when it is pressed.

Comment: The thing is I want the button style to be plain or background to be transparent. UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered or anything else puts the image in a box. Thats why I was using a uibutton

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question. Adding a button to the navigation bar as I showed will always display it with the border, even if you set it to the plain style, as you pointed out. I think it is even mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Now it shows the image but nothing happens when I click on it. Ive tried [rightButton setTarget:self];[rightButton setAction:@selector(refresh:)];

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this

```
    UIButton *refreshButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(292, 9, 27, 27)];
    [refreshButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [refreshButton addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:refreshButton];
    [refreshButton release];
```

It works fine now but I am not really sure if this is the right way of doing it.

Comment: While this might work, I think it's cleaner to use a `UIBarButtonItem`.