# Issue with button on the left side of the uinavigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a button on the left  side of the navigation bar. I also have a UIButton near that button.

Now when I click the button thats below the navigation bar, in many cases, the button on the nab bar gets clicked.

Any idea why this is happening? Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

image: if you click anywhere inside the red button, the top left button of the nav bar still gets pressed.

[image]

code for nav bar button:

```
UIButton *leftButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
[leftButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:NO];
[leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deals.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deals_down.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deals_down.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dealsButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown || UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton] autorelease];
[leftButton release];
```

Comment: Can you please post a picture/image for this scenario.

Comment: Without any code or screenshot, the best guess is that you are actually accidentally tapping the button on the navbar.

Comment: @PeterSarnowski : figure given now. thanks

Comment: @mrunal : figure given now. thanks

Comment: How do you set up the button in the navbar? Please show us the code.

Comment: I agree with fbernardo's answer. And my question is, why do you want to put buttons so close to each other anyways? I find that to be bad design and believe it or not, it's very important in software development/design. For example in a email client would you want delete and reply buttons to be really close to each other? I didn't think so. Here is an excellent read on this topic: http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0465067107/codihorr-20

Answer (score 12):

UINavigationButtons have a much larger tappable area than it's view, Apple made it this way for ease of use. If you really want to have two buttons that close to each other you have to subclass UINavigationBar, more specifically, override the touch events, get the touch coordinates and act as you see fit. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271945/uinavigationbar-uibarbuttonitems-much-larger-click-area-than-required).

Comment: "Apple made it this way for ease of use" - Best to comply with Apple here and lower your own button, really. You're just asking for people to hit the wrong button by mistake if you put your own button too close to the navbar one.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if Apple enlarged the navigationBar's left button (right one is not), it's for usability questions. It's almost the most clicked button of iphone device, so people have got the ability to tap back button in an instinctive way (i never look at the button, I just know the movement).

Have in mind that if you reduce the touch region, users may have difficulties to reach it.

My recommandation, sorry for that, would be to move down 3 or 5px down your 3 buttons.

Comment: Sigh, so many upvotes to the technical answer (which deserves it) and so little for usability related answers such as yours.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a problem with how you're initializing the `UIButton` instance. Typically, we would use `[UIButton buttonWithType:custom];` in your situation.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828781/uibutton-as-uinavigationbar-button), they solved a similar question with the following:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paw.png"];
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height);

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

[rightButton release];
[myButton release];
```

It's not the code you're looking for, but it shows you how to correctly instantiate a `UIButton` instance. Hopefully that will sort out the problems you're having.

Comment: so, in other words, i need to set the type to Custom and set the frame separately. Is that what you are implying ?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm implying - buttons should only be instantiated with `buttonWithType:`. I'm sorry to hear that wasn't your issue - good luck!